# Cannot select IBOutlet in connections

Tags: swift, iboutlet

Im trying to make a simple app but am unable to make an `IBOutlet` like I was able to before, now you don't have the option in swift to change the connection to an Outlet instead of an action. I believe this could be because of the update in the Software as it is now Swift version 9.1. Thank you in advance!

[image]

---

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try to write @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField! and then drag from the editor into the textfield in the Storyboard

Comment: Can you check that, you gave class name of class which you drag your outlet in storyboard.

Comment: Specifically, select the view controller in IB and confirm what the “base class” type is not blank, but rather refers to your specific `ViewController` class...

Comment: I think the problem is, you did not assign a class in your IB for the view. can you check this out?

Comment: @Grumme thanks! But how exactly do I drag from the text editor into the text field?

Answer (score 0):

You have dragged to the exit on the view controller. Drag directly (ctrl) from the storyboard to the code.

Comment: The problem is I did do exactly that but it’s still not working